# Scilab не открывает файл

Tags: matlab, scilab

Подскажите пожалуйства, по какой причинке scilab не может открыть файл?

Сценарий:

```
//Сценарий Pr1_2_1mod.sce вычисления выражений

//Определение функции первого выражения
function b=f1(x, y)
    b= nthroot((x+y)./0.2*x,3).*sin(tan(x).^2);
endfunction

//Определение функции второго выражения
function f=f2(x, y)
    f=exp(x).*(5*x.^2-8*y.^2)+(2*x.^2).*y.^2-10*sin(x).*cos(10*y);
endfunction

//Ввод исходных данных
x=input("Введите x= ");
y=input("Введите y= ");

//Вычисление значений функций
b=f1(x,y);
f=f2(x,y);

//Форматирование вывода результата
format(6);

//Вывод результатов вычисления выражения на экран
disp(b, "b= ");
disp(f, "f= ");
```

Командная строка:

```
--> exec('Pr1_2_1mod', 0);

exec: Не удалось открыть файл Pr1_2_1mod.
```

Я пробовал пересохранять файл, т.к. думал что всё дело в директории, однако это не помогло.

Comment: строки `Pr1_2_1mod` и `Pr1_2_1mod.sce` выгядят несколько разными